# R CMD Check Errors on Examples, Examples Work

Tags: r, cmd

I don't have as much computer science experience so I'm a bit overwhelmed!  I have an R package that is already released on the CRAN.  It passed its CMD checks and worked fine, but I made a change.  It is a Gibbs sampler, so I had it output quantile based CIs, but I changed it to HPD.  But now it's failing it's CMD checks and I don't know why.  The specific problem is with the examples.  I have run the examples and they seem to work.  I have also tried dontrun and donttest, but the same error occurred.  The strangest thing is that R automatically provides the result of its attempts to run the code, with the error report.  But the output provided appears accurate.  Everything seems to be working, except the CMD check flags it as an error and stops the checks.  Please help!  I am really not a computer scientist, so I am very much out of my element!  The error is at the bottom!  Thank you all!

Error:

> base::assign(".dptime", (proc.time() - get(".ptime", pos = "CheckExEnv")), pos = "CheckExEnv")
> base::cat("bcor", base::get(".format_ptime", pos = 'CheckExEnv')(get(".dptime", pos = "CheckExEnv")), "\n", file=base::get(".ExTimings", pos = 'CheckExEnv'), append=TRUE, sep="\t")
> Error in format(x[1L:3L], digits = 7L) : unused argument (digits = 7)
> Calls:  -> 
> Execution halted

Problem code (though this isn't the only one that's had issues, depending on which is tested first):

```
bcor=function(data,iter,burn,seed,CI,S0,nu0,mu0){

  filler=matrix(nrow=ncol(data),ncol=ncol(data))
  for (a in 1:ncol(data)){
    for (b in 1:ncol(data)){
      filler[a,b]=ifelse(a==b,cov(data,use="pairwise.complete.obs")[a,b],0)}}
  filler1=matrix(nrow=ncol(data),ncol=ncol(data))
  for (a in 1:ncol(data)){
    for (b in 1:ncol(data)){
      filler1[a,b]=ifelse(missing(S0),filler[a,b],S0[a,b])}}
  for (a in 1:ncol(data)){
    for (b in 1:ncol(data)){
      filler1[a,b]=ifelse(missing(S0),filler[a,b],S0[a,b])}}
  S0=filler1
  L0=S0
  nu0=ifelse(missing(nu0),ncol(data)*(ncol(data)+1)/2-1,nu0)
  filler2=vector(length=ncol(data))
  for (a in 1:ncol(data)){
    filler2[a]=ifelse(missing(mu0),rep(0,ncol(data)),mu0)
  }
  mu0=filler2
  n=nrow(data)
  ybar=colMeans(data,na.rm=T)
  Sigma=cov(data,use="pairwise.complete.obs")
  seed=ifelse(missing(seed),999,seed)
  iter=ifelse(missing(iter),5000,iter)
  burn=ifelse(missing(burn),iter/2,burn)
  THETA=SIGMA=NULL

  set.seed(seed)
  pct=rep(0,iter+1)
  print(noquote("Sampling, this may take a minute"))
  for(s in 1:iter)
  {
    ###Update theta
    Ln=solve(solve(L0) + n*solve(Sigma))
    mun=Ln%*%(solve(L0)%*%mu0+n*solve(Sigma)%*%ybar)
    theta=mvrnorm(1,mun,Ln)
    ###Update sigma
    Sn=S0 + (t(data)-c(theta))%*%t( t(data)-c(theta))
    Sigma=solve(rwish(nu0+n, solve(Sn)))

    ###Save results
    THETA=rbind(THETA,theta)
    SIGMA=rbind(SIGMA,c(Sigma))
    pct[s+1]=(round(s/iter*10,1))*10
    if(pct[s+1]!=pct[s]){print(noquote(paste(pct[s+1],"%")))}
  }
  CI=ifelse(missing(CI),0.95,CI)
  CI=ifelse(CI>1,CI/100,CI)
  COR=NULL
  mat=matrix(nrow=ncol(data),ncol=ncol(data))
  cor=matrix(nrow=ncol(data),ncol=ncol(data),0)
  print(noquote("Calculating correlations, this may take a minute"))
  pct=rep(0,nrow(SIGMA)-burn+1)
  for (s in burn:nrow(SIGMA)){
    mat=matrix(SIGMA[s,],nrow=ncol(data),ncol=ncol(data))
    for (a in 1:ncol(data)){
      for (b in 1:ncol(data)){
        cor[a,b]=mat[a,b]/sqrt(mat[a,a]*mat[b,b])
        COR=rbind(COR,c(cor))
      }
    }
    num=(s-burn+1)
    denom=(nrow(SIGMA)-burn)
    pct[s-burn+2]=round((num/denom)*10,1)*10
    if(pct[s-burn+2]!=pct[s-burn+1]){print(noquote(paste(pct[s-burn+2],"%")))}

  }
  COR_M=NULL
  COR_SD=NULL
  COR_LL=NULL
  COR_UL=NULL
  for (a in 1:ncol(COR)){
    COR_M[a]=quantile(probs=c(0.5),COR[,a])
    COR_SD=sd(COR[1:nrow(COR),a])
    COR_LL[a]=emp.hpd(COR[,a],conf=CI)[1]
    COR_UL[a]=emp.hpd(COR[,a],conf=CI)[2]

  }

  star_ll=ifelse(COR_LL<0,1,0)
  star_ul=ifelse(COR_UL<0,1,0)
  star=ifelse(star_ll+star_ul==1," ","*")
  COR_M1=paste(round(COR_M,2),star)
  COR1=matrix(COR_M1,nrow=ncol(data),ncol=ncol(data))
  table=data.frame(COR1)
  colnames(table)=c(colnames(data))
  rownames(table)=c(colnames(data))
  diag(table)="1 "
  Out=list()
  Out$MU=THETA
  Out$SIGMA=SIGMA
  Out$M=matrix(COR_M,nrow=ncol(data),ncol=ncol(data))
  Out$SD=matrix(COR_SD,nrow=ncol(data),ncol=ncol(data))
  Out$LL=matrix(COR_LL,nrow=ncol(data),ncol=ncol(data))
  Out$UL=matrix(COR_UL,nrow=ncol(data),ncol=ncol(data))
  Out$Table=table

  return(Out)
```

Comment: Hi Joshua. Welcome to S.O! Could you please find the problem code and add it to your question. Please produce a reproducible example if possible, but I understand this may not be possible if you're developing an entire package.

Comment: That was incredibly fast, thank you so much for getting back to me right away, I really appreciate it!  Code added!

Comment: No worries. That's a weird error you're getting - it's saying `format` has no `digits` argument, but that isn't true; it's right there in the documentation

Comment: Does your package contain a function called `format`? If you're overwriting the base function that might explain it

Comment: My gosh what an idea!  I do have a function called format!  I'm off to bed but I bet that might be it, will try in the morning!

Comment: And I used devtools but I made some edits to the files that had warnings "read only" like the namespace file and the .rd files.  Previously the edits I made helped it get past CMD check issues, so that's why I maintained those edits.  But maybe I went too far!  I regularly use the document function so hopefully any such instance is flagged?  But that definitely could be a source of issue!  Thanks again everybody!

Comment: My gosh, you did it!  I changed the format function to something else and no it works fine!  I can't believe myself, I literally spent five hours yesterday tinkering with the code, and it was just a bad function name!  Thank you so much, lesson learned on that one!  You make me with I had studied computer science, this was a tremendous help!  Have a nice day!

Comment: Glad it worked Joshua. `format` is a generic function which gets called very often in R, it's used to prettify data for printing etc. Even if you didn't study computer science, it's not too late to become an R master! It's a pretty easy(ish) language to learn, and the community is top notch.